# Generate Dynamic Image path in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Here is my image tag which i want to convert in laravel way

```
<img src="public/assets/uploads/driver/<?php echo $DriverDetail['DriverPhoto'];?>">
```

I tried with

```
{{ HTML::image('public/assets/uploads/driver/', 'Driver Photo', array('class' => 'student-listing-photo')) }}
```

But how can i give the value `$DriverDetail['DriverPhoto'];` inside the `HTML::image` tag.

Comment: Do you mean `{{ HTML::image('public/assets/uploads/driver/' . $DriverDetail['DriverPhoto'], 'Driver Photo', array('class' => 'student-listing-photo')) }}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as simple as concatenating two strings :

```
{{ HTML::image('public/assets/uploads/driver/' . $DriverDetail['DriverPhoto'], 'Driver Photo', array('class' => 'student-listing-photo')) }}
```